# How did Uchiha Obito summon Kurama?

Tags: naruto

If Uchiha Madara was the only one who could summon Kurama, how did Obito do it? Also, Naruto was 16 while Kakashi looked about 30, so if Kakashi and Obito were the same age, and Obito summoned Kurama while Naruto was born, he would be younger than Naruto is now.

Comment: In Naruto's world age doesn't determine the ability.

Comment: @mirroroftruth especially if they are like Konohamaru and Naruto and is using the Sexy Jutsu to make guys bleed to death, look at the Hokage's reaction when Naruto does it in front of him and he's a flipping Kage

Comment: @Memor-X yes and he even tried against kaguya at such critical time and it was reverse harem no jutsu and even sakura is bleeding

Comment: Somewhat related: [How can Madara summon Kurama?](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/10099/how-can-madara-summon-kurama)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Obito master the Summoning Jutsu?](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7531/does-obito-master-the-summoning-jutsu)

Comment: I found the height of Obito during the Obito v Yondaime fight kind of odd.  He should've been around kakashi's height but he almost same height as the fourth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, at the beginning of the series, [Kakashi was 26](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kakashi_Hatake), and Naruto was 12. Which makes him (and Obito) only 14 when the Kyuubi attacked.

Second, presumably Obito was able to summon Kurama because Kurama was under his control, and thus acts like a sort of contract between the two. The only other person who was known for summoning Kurama is Madara Uchiha, and Kurama hates his guts.

Comment: oh, i was thinking at the time of the fourth ninja world war

Answer (score 2):

There's a [Contract Seal](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Contract_Seal) to summon tailed beasts. So far, we have only seen Kurama summoned with it. The answer is here [Obito summoning kurama](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7531/does-obito-master-the-summoning-jutsu)